# use boolean locals in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I use pug in nodejs and want to pass boolean locals to pug file and if conditions based on this local.

how can I use firstnameProblem on pug file in if condition like blow?

email.js:

```
email.send({
    template: template,
    message: { to: 'a@a.com' },
    locals: {firstnameProblem:false}
  });
```

html.pug:

```
 ul
      if ${firstnameProblem}
           li Problem in first name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, I can use locals like variable in pug like blow:

html.pug:

```
ul
      if firstnameProblem
           li Problem in first name
```